# php / javascript / ajax submit form > save data to database > update data on website

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have 3 tasks :

1) Submit the message in a textarea when the user press enter button on keyboard or click "submit" button.

2) Use php/mysql to save the message onto database.

3) After save it onto database, need to show the updated message onto the website back.

The problem is... There is no php script that can change "Enter" button event, so I need to use javascript, if I use javascript, I need to create a new page sendMsgToDB.php to submit the data to database by the following javascript/ajax :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gg(e) {  //sumbit the form when user press Enter button
    key = e ? e.which : window.event.keyCode;
    if(key==13) {
           $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "sendMsgToDB.php?msgid=" + msgid,
             data: dataString2,
             success: function() {
                 $('textarea.resposting').val('');
             }
           });
    }
}

$(function() {
        document.getElementById("resposting").onkeypress = gg; 
});
</script>
```

I use mysql to retrieve 10 latest messages from database and use pure php to display the messages onto the website. If I want to show updated messages onto website after the user submit the data through the textarea by pressing "Enter" button on keyboard, sure I need to call the `function Display_New_Msg()` after the data is complete send to database. If I use Javascript/ajax to sumbit data, how to use javascript/ajax/jquery determine whether or not the data is complete send to database?

Seriously I don't like to use javascript/ajax/jquery, but I force to use them because I need to change the "enter" button event, is there a way to change "enter" button event by using php? How to make the press "enter" button act like click "submit" button to submit the form `<form name="frmMsg" action="currentPage.php">`, the action will go to the currentPage.php, so the page is refresh, so it will re-execute the `function Display_New_Msg()` automatically to show the new message, so don't need to dertermine whether or not the data is complete send to database anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I use Javascript/ajax to sumbit data, how to determine whether or not the data is complete send to database?

It all comes down to the response from the resource that's handling the AJAX request.  In this case, `sendMsgToDB.php`.  That script needs to make sure it's doing what it needs to do and that everything's getting into the database (usually a lack of error is sufficient), then sending a response accordingly.  If there is an error on the server, return an HTTP error code (such as a 500 server error) to indicate this.

The jQuery `.ajax()` call then determines the call-back function to use based on the response from the server.  Your code currently handles a successful response:

```
success: function() {
  $('textarea.resposting').val('');
}
```

In order to handle an error response, you'd want a second callback for `error`:

```
error: function() {
 alert('There was an error!');
}
```

The HTTP response codes exist for exactly this purpose, so that clients consuming those responses can easily determine the status of the request.

**Edit:** Conversely (and perhaps more to the spirit of your question, if I'm now re-interpreting you correctly), you can use the jQuery `submit()` function to [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) the form in your key press logic.  That way you don't have to use AJAX and can just use a regular form submission and response, which you indicate to be your preference.  Something like this:

```
if(key==13) {
  $('#myForm').submit();
}
```

Comment: Actually my problem is not want to know the error. I just want to display the new messages onto website after submitting the new message. success: function() determine whether or not the ajax success call the php page, it doesn't determine whether or not the php page success submit the data to database right? So how to determine that?

Comment: @zac1987: It's up to the PHP page to determine that and return an error status accordingly.  The JavaScript can't (and _shouldn't_) know anything about the database, or anything beyond the request/response sent to and received from the server resource (PHP script).  The PHP script should just return an HTTP error if there was an error on the server-side.

Comment: @David, I have php codes : if (isset($_POST['sendResp'])) { //php get data from textarea, then mysql send data to database }. Then I have tested javascript if(key==13) { $('#myForm').submit(); }, but seem it cannot call the php codes. I guess Javascript cannot communicate with php in this way, am I correct? Or I miss something?

Comment: @David, I saw the problem already, javascript does #myForm').submit() but php didn't detect form submission, php detect button sendResp click. May I know how to use php detect form submission?

Comment: @zac1987: JavaScript and PHP don't really communicate with each other. The browser (be it via JavaScript or plain HTML forms) sends an HTTP Post Request to a server resource. The PHP script handles that request and sends a response. There is a hard separation between the two.  PHP doesn't "detect" a form submission, it just receives the request like any other form. When you say that "php didn't detect form submission" what do you mean? If you debug the JavaScript (such as with FireBug), does the request get sent? What is the response?

Comment: Normally php can detect the form submission by detect the submit button click, for example if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])). But now my situation is without a submit button, my situation is "Enter" button. How is php code to detect the "enter" button is pressed? When we use javascript if(key==13){$('#myForm').submit();} to sumbit the form when "Enter" is pressed, how to use php to retrieve the value from the textarea on the form if php can't detect when the "Enter" is pressed and when the form is submitted?

Comment: @zac1987: PHP can read the values from the form post regardless of the presence of a button value or not.  In this case, you'd be (at least) reading the value of the text input in the PHP script.  It's not "detecting" anything, it's just reading values by their keys in the form post.

Comment: @David, I see. So actually I just need to get the textarea value by php script $msg= $_POST['textareaName']; then if($msg!=""){//submit msg to database by mysql}, so simple as that? Okay I go try it now. Thank you.

Comment: @David, Regarding success:function(){ $('textarea.resposting').val('');}, I saw you wrote "ajax is based on the response from the server". So the "success" mean the server side script is executed completely/successfully? So mean after php/mysql have complete sent data to database, then only $('textarea.resposting').val(''); will be executed?

Comment: @zac1987: `success` will be called if the response from the web resource is a normal, expected response (and the client is able to parse it).  `error` will be called if the web resource responds with an error (timeout, 404, 500, etc.).  You can see more information here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/